# How to add embroidered elements to a cloth

Tags: modeling, materials, cloth-simulation, seams

Is there a simple way to add embroidered elements to a cloth simulation? I want to recreate the fabric in this photo. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please help me understand why this q was downvoted. I have researched it prior to asking it here and did not find a solution to this specific issue I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no point to simulate with embroidery, because it just follow the cloth
2. UV coordinates are constant and stable even after simulation and subdivision, so if you know geometry nodes, you can wrap it.
3. There is surface deform modifier, that can make embroidery to follow the surface with deformation
4. You can make only points deformed by surface and then instance threads over them

[image]

offset:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you create those raised dots?

Comment: Just transfom, move along Z initial sphere or translate instances or Normal as offset vector. Added pictures